# how can minimize and maximize window folders in C#

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I'm trying to minimize window folders and applications with voice ( speech recognition ) and this is my code :

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool GetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

    private struct POINTAPI
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    private struct RECT
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;
    }

    private struct WINDOWPLACEMENT
    {
        public int length;
        public int flags;
        public int showCmd;
        public POINTAPI ptMinPosition;
        public POINTAPI ptMaxPosition;
        public RECT rcNormalPosition;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WindowAction_MinimizeNotepad();
    }

    void WindowAction_MinimizeNotepad()
    {
        System.IntPtr app_hwnd;
        WINDOWPLACEMENT wp = new WINDOWPLACEMENT();
        app_hwnd = FindWindow("chrome", null);
        GetWindowPlacement(app_hwnd, ref wp);
        wp.showCmd = 2;
        SetWindowPlacement(app_hwnd, ref wp);
    }
```

i know how to use that code with button but i don't know how to use it with speech recognition so, how can i minimize windows with voice ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First You need to Register for speech recognition event  like:
On Page load

`// Register handler for the SpeechRecognized event.
recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(srEvent_SpeechRecognized);`

Then create a speech recognition event handler, Like :

`void srEvent_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
  this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
}`

Comment: i put that code on program.cs and get this error :  the recognizer doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: i forgot to tell that i'm using : using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Speech.Recognition;

Comment: Please refer : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28725/A-Very-Easy-Introduction-to-Microsoft-NET-Speech-S

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at **Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine**.
Using this you can subscribe to events and proceed with whatever action you want to perform on those events.
Get more information at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378426(v=office.14).aspx